# time query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Looking for some input on whether my approach is correct with this code.

Goal is to take an MSSQL datetime column containing EDT/EST values ex: `2014-12-18 03:33:45.723` and convert it to `varchar(32)` with format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`

```
left(convert(varchar(32),convert(smalldatetime,floor(cast(StartTime as float)*(24/.25))/(24/.25)),120), 
len(convert(varchar(32),convert(smalldatetime,floor(cast(StartTime as float)*(24/.25))/(24/.25)),120)) -3) as ADJUSTED_YYYY_MM_DD_HH24_MI,
```

Comment: Is `TO_CHAR()` not an option?  It supports timezones.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Rephrased question.  It is running against MS SQL.

Comment: So is it not working?  If so, what is it doing and what do you want it to do?  As of right now there is no question in this post.

Comment: @Becuzz No, it works just fine and relatively quick but I just feel it's messy.  I'm hoping someone with more knowledge can suggest better functions to use...

Comment: @AM_Hawk In that case, this might be better on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as long as it fits their standards.  SO is more for fixing broken code.  Code Review helps make working code better.

Answer (score 2):

I was not comming up with correct minutes on the values i tried with your method.  This way seems simpler:

```
CONVERT(varchar(16), StartTime, 20)
```

This will return a varchar(16), so if you need it to return varchar(32) you can convert it explicitly with:

```
convert(varchar(32), CONVERT(varchar(16), StartTime, 20))
```

Comment: I think you can just do `select convert(varchar(16), @StartTime, 20)`.  That is, put the length in the varchar itself.

Comment: You can, but the output type will then be a varchar(16) and the OP wanted to return a varchar(32) type.

Comment: . . That is a good point.  I wonder why the OP would care about the length, if the characters aren't being used.

Comment: Wow... i just checked and the left function is actually modifying the type returned.  I guess you would have to specifically convert the truncated string to varchar(32) explicitly if you needed that.  I'll update the answer.